# Quick workflow not getting triggered

Tags: 2013, workflow

When we create a component in CME, it remains as minor version because quick workflow is not getting triggered. And this happens in only a few environments. In some environment it is working fine.

I am not able to figure out what is the difference between the 2 environments except that we have applied security configuration in the environment where it is working and it is not yet applied in the environment where it is not working.

Could security groups and permissions setup be responsible for not triggering quick workflow? I tried as admin user in both environments.

Update:
By minor version, I mean revision and by quick workflow, I meant the workflow that gets triggered when we don't add the item to a bundle. For example, when workflow for a schema is enabled and a component of that schema type is created, a pop-up asking whether to add to a bundle or not will come. When we select 'not now' a quick workflow is triggered to check in and create a major version of the item.

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean by minor version and quick workflow?

Comment: Minor version - any non-checked in version of an item (0.1, 0.2, etc).

Comment: Yes, authorization can impact Workflow to the extent that you're missing the Groups, Rights, and Permissions expected from the Workflow Process Definition. Double check the Groups and Activities in the Workflow and confirm they're available in the non-working environment. Starting a minor version could imply Workflow *is* working, otherwise the `Save & Close` should save and close (as well as check-in and make a major version of) the item. :-)

Comment: More "standard" Tridion terminology for Minor version is "Revision".

Comment: Updated the question with what I meant by minor version and quick workflow. As per Alvin's answer, I will implement the security permissions and rights and check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authorization includes Users, Groups, Rights, and Permissions.

**Rights**

Authorization *Rights* might impact a user's ability to *participate* in workflow. A Workflow Process Activity *can* include groups that do not have Workflow Management Rights, which deal with associating or configuring Workflow. But groups that don't have Component or Page Management Rights won't be able to work on items in a given Publication.

Workflow includes **Groups** as defined in Workflow Activities as well **Permissions** when creating and editing items.

**Groups**

I suspect a missing Group (or Right) in your case. Although (a lack of) Permissions might cause issues, you'd have issues with even *creating* an item even before Workflow starts. If permissions-related you would not be able to select the right schema or edit an existing item.

*I'm assuming "quick" workflow means a *direct* Workflow Process Association as opposed to an indirect (or Bundle) Workflow (starting Workflow with a Save is quicker than adding items to a bundle, right?).*